# AltBeacon library as a foreground service, issues with Activity elements when becoming active

Tags: android, altbeacon, foreground-service

I am using the latest AltBeacon library and running the reference application with a few mods in the MonitorActivity class as well as utilising the foreground service functionality of bootstrapping.

My app can detect beacons in foreground or from the service but I am struggling ( Android Newbie ) with the Activities visual elements when coming from the service to an active Activity.

The bootstrap region is created in the Application class and then the MonitorActivity is created. The 1st instance of the Activity holds some data and references to an external library used to act on the beacon data.
The library holds context of the Activity that created it.

If the MonitorActivity window is never killed by user intervention, the app works fine. From foreground to background, app behaves as expected.

If the MonitorActivity is killed, the service still runs and appears to have a reference to the initial Activity, as the external library created within that instance still functions. The methods to display the results from the external library fail because the UI elements don't exist anymore.

I would like to set a notification that then loads the Activity to show the result of the beacon data, but in my tests I get another new Activity class, which creates a new external library instance.... not good!

I have tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MonitorActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
    );
```

Thinking it would use the original Activity but it creates a new instance.

The original Activity class must still exist as it's doing the logic that is required.

Is there a way of re-enabling its visual elements to show the result of the external lib created in the original Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement is the key:

> > The 1st instance of the Activity holds some data and references to an external library used to act on the beacon data. The library holds context of the Activity that created it.

You don't say what this library is, but based on your description,  it must be designed to work on visual data in an Activity.  Activities get destroyed, so if properly designed, that library must be designed to handle this situation.  *"How does it recommend it be used with multiple Activities ?**

Are you supposed to hold a reference to it in each activity ?  It it okay if you make a new instance in another activity?  You say this is a problem: "I get another new Activity class, which creates a new external library instance.... not good!" Why is this "not good"?

The answers to these questions should be in the docs for that external library.  Without knowing what it is, it is hard to say more.

Comment: Thanks. The external library ( in-house ) looks after beacon ranging and once a beacon is found, it calls the Server API to get data about that beacon. In this test sample app, the single and only activity then shows the result. As the library does the ranging, we would not want multiple instances if multiple activities are created.

Comment: You could certainly instantiate the library in the Application class' onCreate method, and then provide some kind of singleton wrapper to access it.  This way, only one instance ever gets created.

Comment: Yes I was just implementing that and have managed to get it to work as expected.